# Is EventSource from Eventsource git a drop in replacement for the native MDN EventSource?

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

It seems like [eventsource from the github EventSource](https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource) is an extension to EventSource described by MDN. I am assuming it is native to node. Is this exactly the same with extensibility? I would rather send credentials from my client to my express server rather than using a param.

There is another Stack that mentions SSE as a drop in replacement but the EventSource seems more thorough and Launch Darkley seems even more extensible.